# Is VARCHAR(900) ok or should I go for TEXT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I don't want to use `TEXT` if possible because of the extra overhead. Is it ok to have a `VARCHAR(900)` or some other high number in the `()`?

Comment: which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: will you be selecting this column very often?

Comment: I don't think I'll be selecting it often. I just want to make sure the data I place will not be cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you won't exceed the limits for your column in future its fine.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html

You row however shouldn't exceed the maximum row size fo 65535 bytes. This limit applies to all your columns in that table.

Answer (score 1):

A `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns are just pointed to on disk by an address in the row. Therefore the table can't be stored in memory.

This would mean that every time you select that column you will have to access the file system which will be slower. A recommendation that i have often seen is to then keep the text column as a separate table.

But a limit of 900 should be ok to keep as varchar.

Answer (score 0):

its ok no problem using varchar(900) if you limited to store 900 character than no problem